# Access JSON array in PHP and send to MySQL SELECT

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to receive the data from JSON with PHP and use it in my SELECT query. I have searched everywhere and every solution didn't worked for me.

My Returned JSON data:

```
"{processos:[{"processo":"203"},{"processo":"1430"}]}"
```

My PHP:

```
$ar2 = json_decode($processo2, true);

    $where2 = array();

    foreach($ar2['processo'] as $key=>$val){ 
        $where2[] = $val;
    }
    $where2 = implode(',', $where2);


$pegaSonda = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sonda WHERE n_processo IN ($where2)");
$pegaSonda->execute();
```

What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT**

The code from @wadersgroup worked correctly, but when i change to my variable it stops. This is the way i'm encoding it:

```
$jsonData = array();
$jsonData[] = array("processo" => $automovel->n_processo);
$data['processo2'] .= '{"processos":'.json_encode($jsonData).'}';
```

$data['processo2'] is sending to my AJAX to populate the input and then it receive data back with:

```
$processo2 = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['n_processo2']));
```

Comment: exactly **HOW** is this not working for you? wrong data returned? no data returned? errors thrown? insults issued? dogs kicked?

Comment: @MarcB, in $where2 i'm not receiving the correct data, it was supossed to call a second database table

Comment: `$ar2 = json_decode($processo2, true);` maybe a typo to `$ar2 = json_decode($processos, true);`

Comment: @vinayakj, $processo2 is the input field that's sending the data to PHP.

Comment: then your root becomes `ar2` not `$processos`, so try `$ar2.processos['processo']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are many errors in this code. Try this**

```
    $ar2 = json_decode('{"processos":[{"processo":"203"},{"processo":"1430"}]}', true);

    $where2 = array();

    foreach($ar2['processos'] as $key=>$val){ 
        $where2[] = $val['processo'];
    }
    $where = implode(',', $where2);
    print_r($where);
```

Comment: your code worked like a charm, but with my variable is not working, maybe the way i'm encoding?

Comment: After encoding no character under the string should violet the JSON schema

Comment: I have updated my question with the json_encode code, can you check to see if there's something wrong please?

Comment: TRY IT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      $jsonData = array();
$jsonData[] = array("processo" => json_encode($automovel->n_processo));
$data['processo2'] .= '{"processos":'.$jsonData.'}';

Comment: It returns `"{"processos":Array}"`

Comment: Yes, i think. I'm learning this, so i really don't understand that much

Comment: Do you think that the problem could be the outside double quotes that are returning?

Comment: I m not able to determine the context

Comment: I think it's because of this: i ahve this that encode the input field `$data['processo2'] .= '{"processos":'.json_encode($jsonData).'}';` and to send to ajax, i have this at the last code line: `json_encode($data);`

Comment: Solve it, thanks mate. the problem with my code was because of this: n_processo2: JSON.stringify(n_processo2)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string looks invalid, try instead:

'{"processos":[{"processo":"203"},{"processo":"1430"}]}'

Comment: I've tried that, now it's returning `"{"processos":[{"processo":"203"},{"processo":"1430"}]}"` but still don't work.

Comment: so now try `$ar2.processos['processo'] as $key=>$val`

Answer (score 0):

```
$processo2 = '{"processos": [{ "processo": "203"},{ "processo": "1430"}]}'
$ar2 = json_decode($processo2, true);    
$arr = array_map(function($i) {return $i['processo']; }, $ar2["processos"]);
$where = implode(", ", $arr);
```